# How to access the ClientID from a ServerControl in an external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, controls, external, clientid

At the moment, if I use JavaScript in my SharePoint projects, I add the code into the *.ascx file, in a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` block and create for each element a variable for the `ClientID`.

For example:

```
var test = '<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>';
```

Now I would like to add an external JavaScript to my projects and insert the code there.
But how could I access to the `ClientID`? In the external JavaScript I can’t use `<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>`. I found this: [referencing server controls in external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911042/ajax-asp-net-referencing-server-controls-in-external-file) but I doesn’t understand, how this should work. It would be awesome, if someone could explain my, how to access the ids.

By the way, why this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ClientIDs = {
        test1   : '<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>',
        test2   : '<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>'
        }

    function SetButtonStatus() {    
            alert($(ClientIDs.test1).value);
        }
</script>
```

doesn’t work, no message would be shown?

Greetz

**Edit 1:**

Okay, I could just use textBox1 in my external script?
I did it this way, this is in my *.ascx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ClientIDs = {
        textBox1:    '<%= textBox1.ClientID %>',
        textBox2:    '<%= textBox2.ClientID %>'
    }
</script>
```

In my external script I have just a function to test it:

```
function test () {
alert($(ClientIDs.textBox1).val();
}
```

I also tested it with `"#" +`. Every time test() is executed, I get following error:

```
"document.getElementById(...)" is null or not an object
```

**Edit 2:**
I missed a `)` in the alert. But now I get a message that the variable is not defined.
If I use: `$('#' + ClientIDs.SumbitSearch).val()` I just get the Text and not the ID of my control.

**Edit 3:**
At the moment I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ClientIDs = {
        test1 :    '<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>',
        test2 :    '<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>'
    }

    function test() {
       alert($('#' + ClientIDs.test1).attr("id")));
    }
</script>
```

In my *.ascx file, it works. I don't like that way... It doesn't work in a external JS, the references doesn't work. If someone have some other ideas, which would work with .net 3.5 it would be nice, if he let me know.

Comment: I would avoid defining JS vars in your ASCX file: a page may include multiple controls (or multiple instances of the same control).  If each control defines "var ClientIDs", they'll conflict with each other (damn JS global namespace!).  If you only allow your .ASPX file to define the JS var, at least you know you'll only have one per page.

Comment: Actually, i define the JS var by hand. I found a small tool, which create the `ClientIDs` automatically [link](http://jagregory.com/writings/how-to-use-clientids-in-javascript-without-the-ugliness/). But I can't access to the variable, from my external JS. Greetz.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "define the JS var by hand", and how it prevents collision if the same control defines the same var, but is included on the page multiple times.

Comment: ...same control defines the same var... I'm sorry, I don't understand, what’s the problem? Do you mean, if a wepart is added multiple times the controls use the same id? I tested it. If I use in one website, the same webpart more times, the control id of each control is different.
Webpart 1: TextBox1 ID: `..._yyyyyy_ctl00_TextBox1ID`
Webpart 2: TextBox1 ID: `..._xxxxxx_ctl00_TextBox1ID`
Or do you mean that the JS var, in this case `ClientIDs` exists more than one time? What did it care, if the ClientIDs is private and the complete JS code is in ascx file. Or did I understand that incorrectly?

Comment: If you write the javascript "var ClientIDs" in your ASCX file, then include 2 instances of that control on a page, then "var ClientIDs" will be included twice in the rendered page.  Because JS vars are global, your two "var ClientIDs" definitions will collide.  It will either cause JS errors, or more likely, when JS accesses "ClientIDs" you have no idea which one will be used.

Comment: I’m not confidence with JS, I thought that the vars are not global. Any fix for that problem? I can’t use `clientIDMode="Static`, SP2010 just works with .net 3.5. Greetz.

Comment: I'm something of an intermediate-level JavaScript programmer, so I can't tell you what the accepted-best-practice is, to work around this global variable problem.  But I know there are ways to deal with it.  The book "JavaScript, the Good Parts" by Douglas Crawford is an outstanding book for helping avoid the terrible parts of JS, use good parts, and deal with the gray area in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain, and simplify the question that you're linking to, all they are doing is setting a JavaScript variable from the page/server control, and reading that variable from an external JavaScript file.

For example, your *.ascx file will contain this JavaScript:

```
var textBox1 = '<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>';
```

Then, your external JavaScript file can just reference the variable `textBox1`.

Now, there are other ways to accomplish this. If you're using ASP.NET 4, you can use a new property [ClientIDMode](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx) to prevent ASP.NET from changing your IDs. If you're not using ASP.NET 4, could also simply add a CSS class to the elements you want to select, and just change your jQuery selector to use a class (slightly slower than using an ID though).

Lastly, you'll need to use the `#` when evaluating a jQuery selector for an element id, so this will work:

```
alert($('#' + ClientIDs.test1).val());
```

Comment: See my **Edit 1:**. Thank's for your answer. Greetz.

Comment: Updated the jQuery selector, mine was totally wrong. Also, the method is `val()` not `values`.

Comment: Upvote for ClientIDMode - I'd forgotten about that.  It solves the .JS / ClientID problem.  Of course, it adds the problem that each control/page is responsible for ensuring unique naming of its elements.

Comment: True, using `clientIDMode="Static"` forces you to do a bit of thinking/double checking ahead of time. But for the cases where you only have one instance of a control, it's much nicer from a CSS/JS perspective.

Comment: Okay, I will have a try with the 'clientIDMode'. But now i will make a break. I give you tomorrow feedback if everything works fine. Greetz.

Comment: The `clientIDMode` methode looks good, but how could I select the .net 4 Frameworks as main framework for my project? I just could choose 3.5. I have installed the "Targeting Pack" and the "Runtime". If I create a new project, the framework is set to 4, but in the project properties the 3.5 framework is chosen again. Greetz. **Edit:** Is it true, that sharepoint 2010 doesn't support .net 4? ... So the `clientIDMode` methode dies...

Answer (score 1):

In the ASP page:

```
<script>
    var test2 = '<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>'
</script>
```

And in external JavaScript access `TextBox2` in this way:

```
documnet.getelementByid(test2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never found a solution to this that I like, but I've implemented a couple work-arounds that aren't **completely** horrible:

- For the JS code which must reference specific page elements, define it in the .aspx file, so you have access to <%= btnFoo.ClientID %>.  Those functions can call common heavy-lifting functions in your .js file.
- Define javascript variables in your .aspx file to hold the ClientID values.  Functions in your .js file can reference those variables to get the client IDs.  Of course, those functions will only work correctly on pages which define the expected variables.

Perhaps other SO'ers will have more elegant solutions to this problem - I look forward to seeing other responses.

Comment: That's true. I also found no solution, which is quite nice. Greetz.

Comment: If you do not have multiple instances of your user control on a page, the most elegant solution would be to set `clientIDMode="Static"` in the `<pages>` node of your web.config file. This was introduced in ASP.NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

Use explicity global parameter.

window.clientId= '<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>';

it means that you have gloabal variable "cilentId". And then you can use it everywhere.

Comment: My understanding is that any use of the "var" keyword in JS is the same thing as applying thing var to the "window" object (except vars defined specifically within the scope of a function).  Perhaps my understanding is incorrect?